# C# in VS2005: will this() execute the base constructor code for an inherited class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

For C# in VS2005, will calling `this()` in an inherited class cause the execution of the base constructor?

EDIT:  How can I avoid having to re-write the `x` and `y` assignments?  Note, I do **not** want the MyObject(int num) constructor to execute the base() contructor.

```
public class MyObject : MyParentObject { 

int x; 
int y; 
int z; 

public MyObject() { 
    x = 5; 
    y = 10; 
} 

public MyObject(int num) : base(num) { 
    x = 5; 
    y = 10; 
    z = num; 
}
```

Comment: You have to call the base constructor, maybe Inheritance is not the solution you require.

Answer (score 5):

[`base()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce%28VS.71%29.aspx) will be called implicitly by the first constructor to run in the derived class:

```
public MyObject() {
    x = 5;
    y = 10;
}

public MyObject(int setZ) : this() {
    z = setZ;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public MyObject() : base() {
    x = 5;
    y = 10;
}

public MyObject(int setZ) : this() {
    z = setZ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameterless base constructor will be called implicitly unless you explicitly call a paramterized base constructor.

If you have

```
class Base { }
class Foo : Base { public Foo() { } }
```

It is no different from saying

```
class Foo : Base { public Foo() : base() { } }
```

So if you have a parameterized constructor for Foo, `base()` will be called no matter what you do with `this()` *unless* you also have a parameterized constructor for `Base` that you explicitly call.

```
class Base
{
    public Base() { }
    public Base(int bar) { }
}

class Foo : Base
{
    public Foo() : base() { }
    public Foo(int bar) : base(bar) { }
    // also legal: 
    // public Foo() : base(1) { }
    // public Foo(int bar) : base(1) { }
    // public Foo(int bar) : base() { }
    // public Foo(int bar) { } /* uses implicit call to base() */
    // public Foo() { } /* ditto */
}
```

Either way, the base class will get instantiated *first* either through the parameterless constructor (implicitly or explicitly) or through the parameterized constructor (explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
    class MainClass
{
    MainClass()
    {
        //do something
    }

}

class MyClass : MainClass
{
    MyClass()
        : base()
    {
        // do something else
    }

}
```

Calling base() will cause it to run the base constructor before the current constructor.

Comment: Interesting. I answer first, then you answer the same thing, and all of the sudden my answer has one down vote. Gee, I wonder what's going on here.

Comment: Whether or not you call `base()`, it will still run before the derived class constructor, assuming the base class has a parameter-less constructor *and* you do not explicitly call a parameterized base constructor. In any event, the base class is going to be constructed before the derived class.

Comment: This answer isn't wrong, but it's unnecessary.  And @Esteban, I'm the one that down-voted you.

Comment: @Esteban, I didn't see your answer until after I clicked the submit button. There was literally 13 seconds between the two posts. If you're worried about being copied, I really can't type that fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseClass
{
   BaseClass()
   {

   }
}

class MyClass : BaseClass
{
   MyClass(int? id) : base()
   {

   }

   MyClass() : this(null)
   {

   }
}
```

`MyClass() : this(null)` will call base via `MyClass(int? id)`

Or you could swap it around and make `MyClass(int? id) : this()` and `MyClass() : base()` either way, the base constructor will be called.

The paramater-less constructor (if there is one) is called if nothing is specified, or a compiler error will result (if you only have a base constructor with parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to not instantiate your base class at any point? That's not possible; you have to explicitly or implicitly call a base constructor, whether you rewrite the field assigments or not.

It's sounds like this isn't the behavior you're looking for (because it calls `base()` implicitly, but then again, so does your code), but this saves you the rewrite:

```
public class MyObject : MyParentObject { 

int x; 
int y; 
int z; 

public MyObject() { 
    x = 5; 
    y = 10; 
} 

public MyObject(int num) : this() { 
    z = num; 
}
```

Why specifically do you want to avoid calling the base class constructor?